# Python Web Scraping for loop error while executing

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am new tp Python Programming. Any Help will be much appreciated .I am unable to execute a Python web scrape program to scrape data to csv file. 
Code I am using is:

```
import urllib.request
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
#from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

f = open("dataout.csv", 'w', newline= '')
writer = csv.writer(f)
url= "https://directory.corp.intranet/cmsviewer/scorecards/MDL-ByDEVDBAMGR.html"
def login():
   username = input("Enter you Username:")
   password = getpass("Enter you password:")

   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe')
   driver.get(url)

   cuid_user = driver.find_element_by_name("f_loginname")
   cuid_user.send_keys(username)

   password_cuid = driver.find_element_by_name("f_loginpassword")
   password_cuid.send_keys(password)

   enter_button = driver.find_element_by_name("frm_login")
   enter_button.submit()


def scarpe():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
    tbody = soup('table' , {"class":"scorecardtable tablesorter"}[0].find_all('tr')
    for row in tbody:
        cols = row.findChildren(recursive=false)
        cols = [ele.test.strip() for ele in cols]
        writer.writerow(cols)
        print(cols)

login()
scarpe()
```

Also Error I am getting is :
C:Scripts>python scrape.py
  File "scrape.py", line 29
    for row in tbody:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. Also I want to set parameter that function SCRAPE() executes only when Function Login was successful, let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For executing the scrape() function, simply return a value from login if it's successful and check that value before running scrape().

```
def login():
    username = input("Enter you Username:")
    password = getpass("Enter you password:")

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)

    cuid_user = driver.find_element_by_name("f_loginname")
    cuid_user.send_keys(username)

    password_cuid = driver.find_element_by_name("f_loginpassword")
    password_cuid.send_keys(password)

    enter_button = driver.find_element_by_name("frm_login")
    enter_button.submit()
    driver.wait(3)
    #depending on the returned url after logging in, find a way to check if the login succeeded, either by url content of HTML content assigned in variable logged. Can't help you with that without the result page. 

    return logged

def scarpe():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
    tbody = soup('table' , {"class":"scorecardtable tablesorter"})[0].find_all('tr')
    for row in tbody:
        cols = row.findChildren(recursive=false)
        cols = [ele.test.strip() for ele in cols]
        writer.writerow(cols)
        print(cols)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logged = login()
    if logged : scarpe()
```

Comment: HI Sebastian,Thanks for this .. I am still getting error after applying your update. Seems to be For loop error.
C:\Scripts>python Scraped.py
  File "Scraped.py", line 30
    for row in tbody:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thanks Sebastien ...I was missing a ' ) ' in tbody variable..My bad